# Symfony forms - Country choice Locale not symfony's default

Tags: php, forms, symfony, internationalization

I'm trying to render a form select with countries. For that purpose, I'm using the form select choice type "country".

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/country.html

Everything is fine at this point. The problem comes with internationalization. If a user uses a different language, cities are not being translated.

Following the docs, the "country" choice uses "Locale::getDefault()" to guess the locale. But it comes with a wrong locale.

```
echo \Locale::getDefault(); // echoes en.

$request = $this->get('request');
echo $request->getLocale(); // echoes symfony current user locale. fr_FR.
```

How can I use the current symfony locale on "country" choice select?

Comment: according to [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdefault.php) you can also set default locale using: `ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'de-DE');`

Comment: or even better use : `locale_set_default('fr');` and so on.. Maybe you could set default locale and then reset it if needed

Comment: It's strange that symfony's form country choice doesn't get his own default locale. That's why i think i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Following [Nikos M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3591273/nikos-m) advice, i've created an event listener to override default locale.

```
namespace Foo\AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;


/**
 * Event Listener that overrides intl default locale for "country" choice form
 *
 * @author some.cool.guy@foo.com
 */
class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    public function onFilterControllerEvent(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $locale = $request->getLocale();

        \Locale::setDefault($locale);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // Before controller load due to BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => array(array('onFilterControllerEvent', 17)),

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I have passed hours trying to configure that... Your solution is working fine :)